# Objective-c - How to serialize audio file into small packets that can be played?

Tags: objective-c, serialization, audio, macos, audioqueueservices

So, I would like to get a sound file and convert it in packets, and send it to another computer. I would like that the other computer be able to play the packets as they arrive.

I am using AVAudioPlayer to try to play this packets, but I couldn't find a proper way to serialize the data on the peer1 that the peer2 can play.

The scenario is, peer1 has a audio file, split the audio file in many small packets, put them on a NSData and send them to peer2. Peer 2 receive the packets and play one by one, as they arrive.

Does anyone have know how to do this? or even if it is possible?

EDIT:

Here it is some piece of code to illustrate what I would like to achieve.

```
// This code is part of the peer1, the one who sends the data
- (void)sendData
{
    int packetId = 0;
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myAudioFile" ofType:@"wav"];

    NSData *soundData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];
    NSMutableArray *arraySoundData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Spliting the audio in 2 pieces
    // This is only an illustration
    // The idea is to split the data into multiple pieces
    // dependin on the size of the file to be sent
    NSRange soundRange;
    soundRange.length = [soundData length]/2;
    soundRange.location = 0;
    [arraySoundData addObject:[soundData subdataWithRange:soundRange]];
    soundRange.length = [soundData length]/2;
    soundRange.location = [soundData length]/2;
    [arraySoundData addObject:[soundData subdataWithRange:soundRange]];

    for (int i=0; i<[arraySoundData count]; i++)
    {
        NSData *soundPacket = [arraySoundData objectAtIndex:i];

        if(soundPacket == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"soundData is nil");
            return;
        }       

        NSMutableData* message = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        NSKeyedArchiver* archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:message];
        [archiver encodeInt:packetId++ forKey:PACKET_ID];
        [archiver encodeObject:soundPacket forKey:PACKET_SOUND_DATA];
        [archiver finishEncoding];      

        NSError* error = nil;
        [connectionManager sendMessage:message error:&error];
        if (error) NSLog (@"send greeting failed: %@" , [error localizedDescription]);

        [message release];
        [archiver release];
    }

    [soundData release];
    [arraySoundData release];
}
```

```
// This is the code on peer2 that would receive and play the piece of audio on each packet

- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];

    if ([unarchiver containsValueForKey:PACKET_ID])
        NSLog(@"DECODED PACKET_ID: %i", [unarchiver decodeIntForKey:PACKET_ID]);

    if ([unarchiver containsValueForKey:PACKET_SOUND_DATA])
    {
        NSLog(@"DECODED sound");
        NSData *sound = (NSData *)[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:PACKET_SOUND_DATA];

        if (sound == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"sound is nil!");

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"sound is not nil!");

            AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [AVAudioPlayer alloc];

            if ([audioPlayer initWithData:sound error:nil])
            {
                [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
                [audioPlayer play];
            } else {
                [audioPlayer release];
                NSLog(@"Player couldn't load data");
            }   
        }
    }

    [unarchiver release];
}
```

So, here is what I am trying to achieve...so, what I really need to know is how to create the packets, so peer2 can play the audio.

It would be a kind of streaming. Yes, for now I am not worried about the order that the packet are received or played...I only need to get the sound sliced and them be able to play each piece, each slice, without need to wait for the whole file be received by peer2.

Thanks!

Comment: Question is very vague - what specifically are you having difficulty with ?

Comment: Hi Paul, So, I as I said, I need to get an audio file, serialize it (split in small packets) and send it from peerA to peerB. PeerB whould receive them and play. Now, I can get the content of a file inside an NSData e split it in small packet, send them to peerB, but peerB is only able to play the audio file when received all packets. What I would like to do is a kind of streaming, but I need to control how the packets would be sent to peerB. Is it clear now?

Comment: That helps a little - you should probably edit your original question and add this extra information to help clarify it. I guess the nub of your question is "what API should I use to play streamed audio on OS X ?". You might also want to add an `osx` tag in place of one of the others, as it's not immediately apparently what platform you're talking about here.

Comment: Hi Paul, I am talking about Objective-C, so I would be able to do this among Mac's, iPhones, iPod touch. I will edit the post with a piece of code with waht I am doing now, and showing where the limitation is.

Comment: Hi vfn, can you please share your final code please. I am trying to do similar but little bit different. I am using your technique to convert Sound to NSData to merge multiple sounds files but it isn't playing converted/merged file. Could you please help me out here. I have posted my question at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359780/sound-to-nsdata-to-merge-multiple-sound-files. Thanks.

Comment: hii sir you work socketing programing please help mi i work udp socket project i send mp4 file from server but some data is missing how to solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are solving wrong task, because **AVAudioPlayer** capable play only whole audiofile. You should use **Audio Queue Service** from **AudioToolbox** framework instead, to play audio on packet-by-packet basis. In fact you need not divide audiofile into real sound packets, you can use any data block like in your own example above, but then you should read received data chuncks using **Audiofile Service** or **Audio File Stream Services** functions (from **AudioToolbox**) and feed them to audioqueue buffers.

If you nevertheless want to divide audiofile into sound packets, you can easily do it with Audiofile Service functions. Audiofile consist of header where its properties like number of packets, samplerate, number of channels etc. are stored, and  raw sound data.

Use **AudioFileOpenURL** to open audiofile and take all its properties with **AudioFileGetProperty** function. Basicaly you need only kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat and kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount properties:

```
AudioFileID  fileID;    // the identifier for the audio file
CFURLRef     fileURL = ...; // file URL
AudioStreamBasicDescription format; // structure containing audio header info
    UInt64  packetsCount;

AudioFileOpenURL(fileURL, 
    0x01, //fsRdPerm,                       // read only
    0, //no hint
    &fileID
);

UInt32 sizeOfPlaybackFormatASBDStruct = sizeof format;
AudioFileGetProperty (
    fileID, 
    kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat,
    &sizeOfPlaybackFormatASBDStruct,
    &format
);

propertySize = sizeof(packetsCount);
AudioFileGetProperty(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount, &propertySize, &packetsCount);
```

Then you can take any range of audiopackets data with:

```
   OSStatus AudioFileReadPackets (
       AudioFileID                  inAudioFile,
       Boolean                      inUseCache,
       UInt32                       *outNumBytes,
       AudioStreamPacketDescription *outPacketDescriptions,
       SInt64                       inStartingPacket,
       UInt32                       *ioNumPackets,
       void                         *outBuffer
    );
```

Comment: Hi Vladmir,

I will take a look on it. I have been reading some stuff about Audio Queue Service, but I haven't had time to spend playing around with it. Would you be able to help me on how I would configure the functions "sendData" and "receiveData" to work with the Queue Service? Or would you be able to provide a good example that uses it? Thanks.

Comment: in this case no need of special data formating because they are sound data, just send/receive like any other binary data. You only should ensure that you have large enough block to begin play - containing all header data. Its size depends on format  e.g. 44 bytes for lpcm wav, probably more for compressed formats - don't know exact values. When play you try read successive blocks of audiodata, and if fail (AudioFileReadPackets returns 0 packets), but not all data loaded yet pause till receive more.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, Could you help me on how to receive the packets and put them on the queue to be played? What i am doing now is, reading each packet with AudioFileReadPackets, and send them to the client. How can i get this packet and play all the queue?

Comment: If you prefer, i can create another question related to this one and so you can answer it. Thanks!

Comment: plase specify are your speking about data transfer or about playing already received data?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I need help on how to enqueue and play the received packets.....On the peerA I will serialize and use a method to send the packets to peerB. On peerB I will have a method that listens to the connection, waiting for new packets, and when a new packet arrives, it gets the packet, enqueue and start playing when the first packet arrives. So, what info should I send to peerB that would be necessary to create the queue and play the arriving packets? Cheers

Comment: There are 3 ways.


1. Not bother about audiodata structure and transfer data from peerA audiofile by blocks of any size, adding them to temp file on peerB, and you can begin play this file when only some KBytes are transfered. (I think this way is best because you can replay file or seek to any position even if it is very large).

2. Put transferred data (on peerB) to stream and play them using AudioFileStream functions. (but no seek functionality) 

3. (I see you try to implement this case) Read data with audio file Audiofile Service on peerA then transfer parsed packets.

Comment: begin new question because comments is not handy for formatted text, and I will add code.

Comment: Hi, I think that the first option would be great, if it works for partial files....for example, imagine that peerA is sending the packets and peerB is receiving, and them, peerC join and receive the packets too, but from any part of the file....not necessary form the beginning....would that work? or only the scenario 2 would do it....Let me know what you think and I will create the question based on it. Thanks

Comment: First variant is simplest and most flexible for any case. And in all cases you need audiofiles properties. Having them you can play data from any part, not necessary from begining. Second is least flexible. Third is like first but more complicated and with size limitation.

Answer (score 8):

Here is simplest class to play files with AQ
Note that you can play it from any point (just set currentPacketNumber)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface AudioFile : NSObject {
    AudioFileID                     fileID;     // the identifier for the audio file to play
    AudioStreamBasicDescription     format;
    UInt64                          packetsCount;           
    UInt32                          maxPacketSize;  
}

@property (readwrite)           AudioFileID                 fileID;
@property (readwrite)           UInt64                      packetsCount;
@property (readwrite)           UInt32                      maxPacketSize;

- (id) initWithURL: (CFURLRef) url;
- (AudioStreamBasicDescription *)audioFormatRef;

@end


//  AudioFile.m

#import "AudioFile.h"


@implementation AudioFile

@synthesize fileID;
@synthesize format;
@synthesize maxPacketSize;
@synthesize packetsCount;

- (id)initWithURL:(CFURLRef)url{
    if (self = [super init]){       
        AudioFileOpenURL(
                         url,
                         0x01, //fsRdPerm, read only
                         0, //no hint
                         &fileID
                         );

        UInt32 sizeOfPlaybackFormatASBDStruct = sizeof format;
        AudioFileGetProperty (
                              fileID, 
                              kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat,
                              &sizeOfPlaybackFormatASBDStruct,
                              &format
                              );

        UInt32 propertySize = sizeof (maxPacketSize);

        AudioFileGetProperty (
                              fileID, 
                              kAudioFilePropertyMaximumPacketSize,
                              &propertySize,
                              &maxPacketSize
                              );

        propertySize = sizeof(packetsCount);
        AudioFileGetProperty(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount, &propertySize, &packetsCount);
    }
    return self;
} 

-(AudioStreamBasicDescription *)audioFormatRef{
    return &format;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    AudioFileClose(fileID);
    [super dealloc];
}



//  AQPlayer.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AudioFile.h"

#define AUDIOBUFFERS_NUMBER     3
#define MAX_PACKET_COUNT    4096

@interface AQPlayer : NSObject {
@public
    AudioQueueRef                   queue;
    AudioQueueBufferRef             buffers[AUDIOBUFFERS_NUMBER];
    NSInteger                       bufferByteSize;
    AudioStreamPacketDescription    packetDescriptions[MAX_PACKET_COUNT];

    AudioFile * audioFile;
    SInt64  currentPacketNumber;
    UInt32  numPacketsToRead;
}

@property (nonatomic)               SInt64          currentPacketNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain)       AudioFile       * audioFile;

-(id)initWithFile:(NSString *)file;
-(NSInteger)fillBuffer:(AudioQueueBufferRef)buffer;
-(void)play;

@end 

//  AQPlayer.m

#import "AQPlayer.h"

static void AQOutputCallback(void * inUserData, AudioQueueRef inAQ, AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer) {
    AQPlayer * aqp = (AQPlayer *)inUserData;
    [aqp fillBuffer:(AudioQueueBufferRef)inBuffer];
}

@implementation AQPlayer

@synthesize currentPacketNumber;
@synthesize audioFile;

-(id)initWithFile:(NSString *)file{
    if ([self init]){
        audioFile = [[AudioFile alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:file]];
        currentPacketNumber = 0;
        AudioQueueNewOutput ([audioFile audioFormatRef], AQOutputCallback, self, CFRunLoopGetCurrent (), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &queue);
        bufferByteSize = 4096;
        if (bufferByteSize < audioFile.maxPacketSize) bufferByteSize = audioFile.maxPacketSize; 
        numPacketsToRead = bufferByteSize/audioFile.maxPacketSize;
        for(int i=0; i<AUDIOBUFFERS_NUMBER; i++){
            AudioQueueAllocateBuffer (queue, bufferByteSize, &buffers[i]);
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc{
    [audioFile release];
    if (queue){
        AudioQueueDispose(queue, YES);
        queue = nil;
    }
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)play{
    for (int bufferIndex = 0; bufferIndex < AUDIOBUFFERS_NUMBER; ++bufferIndex){
        [self fillBuffer:buffers[bufferIndex]];
    }
    AudioQueueStart (queue, NULL);

}

-(NSInteger)fillBuffer:(AudioQueueBufferRef)buffer{
    UInt32 numBytes;
    UInt32 numPackets = numPacketsToRead;
    BOOL isVBR = [audioFile audioFormatRef]->mBytesPerPacket == 0 ? YES : NO;
    AudioFileReadPackets(
                         audioFile.fileID,
                         NO,
                         &numBytes,
                         isVBR ? packetDescriptions : 0,
                         currentPacketNumber,
                         &numPackets, 
                         buffer->mAudioData
                         );

    if (numPackets > 0) {
        buffer->mAudioDataByteSize = numBytes;      
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer (
                                 queue,
                                 buffer,
                                 isVBR ? numPackets : 0,
                                 isVBR ? packetDescriptions : 0
                                 );


    } 
    else{
        // end of present data, check if all packets are played
        // if yes, stop play and dispose queue
        // if no, pause queue till new data arrive then start it again
    }
    return  numPackets;
}
```

Comment: to play data when begining of file is not available (for peerC in  vfn previous comment) you initially should send     AudioStreamBasicDescription  format;, 
    UInt64 packetsCount;,          
    UInt32 maxPacketSize; to create audiqueue, then feed any segment from file to AudioFileStream with AudioFileStreamParseBytes and in AudioFileStream_PacketsProc you get parsed data to fill AQ buffer.

Comment: I am sure I have a audio formatting issue after writing NSData to sound file but not getting what to do. Could you please help me out here. I have posted my question at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359780/sound-to-nsdata-to-merge-multiple-sound-files Thanks.

Comment: Moreover, could you please tell me what does AQCacheablePlayer and AQPropertyListenerCallback refers to in your code. For me XCode reports them as an undeclared identifiers. I have included AudioToolbox framework.

Comment: @AppleDeveloper, thank you for pointing on error - I've missed it when extracted sample from real class. Fixed.

Comment: AQPropertyListenerCallback is a callback function called when corresponding property is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Apple already has written something that can do this: AUNetSend and AUNetReceive. AUNetSend is an effect AudioUnit that sends audio to an AUNetReceive AudioUnit on another computer.

Unfortunately these AUs are not available on the iPhone, though.

Comment: Hi sbooth,

Thanks for that! I need to controll the way that the messages are sent. So, AUNetSend/Receive don't help with my problem. Thanks again.